# What's the best way to auto update per record data periodically

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, sql-server-2016

i have situation where i need to insert transaction order data from webAPI to database (SQL Server 2016) that will be automatically flagged as expired within 5 minutes.

What comes to my mind is :

1. Create scheduler (Sql Job agent or Windows scheduler) that will trigger update query in every second to check if any record create_time is already exceed 5 minutes , and then update the expired_status = 1

But is it a good choice ? Since in my case there could be a lot of unprocessed data in every second and maybe causing deadlock (?).

Or any better method to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following with computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE transaction_table
ADD Expired_Status AS CAST(case when datediff(minute, create_time, getdate()) > 5 then 1 else 0 end AS bit)
GO
```

Please see example **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7dea7/3)**.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a scheduled task. You can create a computed column "IsExpired" that checks if the row is expired or not.

Comment: haven't heard of computed column before , i tried it and it works . Thanks